# Вывод текста при нажатии на кнопку в сервлете

Tags: java, html, сервер, servlet, client

Только наал изучать сервлеты, нашел задание: клиент нажимает на кнопку, сервер выводит ему текст. Если, например, клиент 5 раз нажал на кнопку, ему выводится 5 строчек текста. Не знаю как реализовать.

Comment: Один клик = один текст?

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter;

void btnClick(){
counter++;
int i = counter;
while(i > 0){
    print("text");
    i--;
}
}
```

Comment: а как присвоить нажатие кнопки методу?